# Help with gaussian integral

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I need to solve this gaussian integral:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} (2\pi)^{-n/2}\mid \Sigma\mid ^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u-Kx)^T\Sigma ^{-1}(u-Kx)} u^TRu \,\mathrm du$$
It is the integral of a multivariate guassian with mean $Kx$ and variance $\Sigma$.
$R$ is a constant. $R$ and $K$ are symmetric of size $n$. $u$ is a column vector of size $n$.

I am reading a paper and I have to demonstrate an equation, but it is the first time I encounter multivariate gaussian integral.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I have done so far:

Substitute $v=(u-Kx)$:
$$
(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\mid \Sigma\mid ^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_\mathbb{U} e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^T\Sigma ^{-1}v} (v+Kx)^TR(v+Kx) d\text{u}
$$
Split the integral and solve the parts one by one (notice that $x^TKRv = (Kx)^T(v^TR)^T=v^TRKx$):
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^T\Sigma ^{-1}v} v^TRv d\text{u}=?
$$
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^T\Sigma ^{-1}v} v^TRKx d\text{u}=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^T\Sigma ^{-1}v} x^TKRv d\text{u}
$$
$$
=-e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^T\Sigma ^{-1}v} \Sigma RKx \mid_{-\infty}^\infty=?
$$
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^T\Sigma ^{-1}v} x^TKRKx d\text{u}=((2\pi)^n \mid \Sigma \mid)^{\frac{1}{2}}x^TKRKx
$$

I have no idea how to solve the first.

About the second, I think it should be $0$ (seeing the final result that I have to prove) but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is equivalent with calculating the expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E}[u^TRu],
$$
where $u \sim \mathcal{N}(Kx,\Sigma)$. From matrix cookbook [1](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), eq. (296) you have:
$$
\mathbb{E}[u^TRu] = \mathrm{Tr}(R\Sigma) + x^TK^TRKx.
$$